# What’s with “一题问题”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, measure-word

Duolingo keeps drilling me on this sentence:

> 我不懂这一题问题

My question is, why “一题问题”? It looks to me as though *一题*, coming as it does after *这*, were being used as a classifier for *问题*. But according to Wiktionary, the classifier is *个*.

So what’s going on with *一题*, and is it making its sentence mean something different from

> 我不懂这个问题

Apparently Duolingo used to have [a forum page on this](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/25424856/%E6%88%91%E4%B8%8D%E6%87%82%E8%BF%99%E4%B8%80%E9%A2%98%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%E3%80%82), but they have—most unhelpfully—shut down all of their fora.
A Google search turns up [essentially the same question on hinativ.com](https://hinative.com/questions/19988079%20Hello) along with this terse response:

> 错的
> 我不懂这个问题

So is Duolingo just wrong on this?

Comment: I think you are correct. The sentences online are not always correct.

Comment: This reminds me of a question I asked a while back about 一条油条: [Are 根 (gēn) and 条 (tiáo) both measure words for 油条 (yóutiáo)?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/27171/8099)

Answer (score 2):

Some words can have multiple-choice of classifiers

个，條， 道， and 题 can all be the classifier for 问题

个，节， 堂， and 课 can all be the classifier for 课堂

Comment: So does the sentence that uses “这一题” mean exactly the same as the version that replaces it with *个*?     Seeing both *这* and *一* (and encountering them slammed together) confuses me.

Comment: Yes, the meaning is the same. 个 is a general classifier that fits many nouns and 题 is a particular classifier only appliable to a selected few words like 问题, 对联 ( 一对对联 = 一题对联)

Comment: 这一 means "this one" (这一个人 = this one person)

Answer (score 1):

這一課有佷多練習(问)題 (say 10), 我不懂这一题(/個/道/條)问題 - This lesson has many practice questions, I don't understand this question (say question 4).

题/個/道/條 all are classifiers for 问題, with 個 and 道 are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say it correctly, You can say,

(1) 我不懂这一个问题。

(2) 我不懂这个问题。

(3) 我不懂这个题。

(4) 我不懂这题。

(5) 我不懂这个。 (only if you have the context.)

But, you cannot say,

我不懂这一**题**问题。The measuring word for 问题 is 个, not 题。

Comment: 題 is a classifier. e.g. "十題中答對了一題" (问题) It is just a more specific classifier for "问题"(typically for questions that appear in a test(This kind of 问题 is also known as 試题), not "问题" in a broad sense which can mean "problem"; 个 can be a classifier for 问题 doesn't mean there's no other classifier for it

Comment: quote:"The measuring word for 问题 is 个" How about 一條问题?